# Windows recovery partition

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, efi, boot-partition, partition-copy

If i were to duplicate an OS partition such as windows 10, and both versions are bootable, would either version be able to access the recovery partition? For simplicities sake, original Windows OS partition name is: Original, and duplicated windows OS partition name is: Duplicate. If both OS partitions could access the recovery partition would the recovery partition only ever factory reset Original or Duplicate, or would it do it to whatever it was that requested use of it? The ssd also has an EFI system partition on it too. Would that need to be duplicated with the OS too?

Comment: @Ramhound This should be an answer to this question, imho.

Answer (score -1):

I'm 98% sure that if you were to run the recovery partition to factory reset the hard drive to its original state it would have to ignore the second partition. The second partition would not be identified in the recovery partitions code so it wouldn't know what to do with it. but i could see the recovery partition having an error with the size of the disk. Windows has come a long way so i think it wouldn't even look at that partition as part of the original windows partition and would just ignore it.

Comment: I think thats what im going for.   When windows does a factory reset it only deals with the windows partition so thats what i want. But. If i had a duplicate of the windows partition would the recovery partition factory reset the original windows or the duplicate?

Comment: The recovery partition would go at what ever partition it meats first in its boot order. so basically by default your original partition is "before" your second partition even tho you use a boot loader to pick your partition. when the recovery runs it can select a partition it uses lines of code to select what to restore. i would go for the original partition.

Comment: So even if the second windows partition could boot into recovery partition and it tried to do a factory reset,the factory reset would only reset the first partition?

Comment: And thank you for the help on both questions!!

Comment: unfortunately yes you would almost have to program the recovery to give you and menu of what to restore. witch inst impossible just really hard :P and no problem